# React: Better way of mapping this data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, axios

So this is a continuation of previous questions. I just started using react and I've managed to fetch a xml file, convert it to json and then loop through the data. But I think there should be a better way to go through what I've done as I'm using a function I found on another SO answer and then used a map() within it.

Anyways here's the breakdown of my code.

Fetching the xml and converting to json:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eMatsiyana/e315b60a2930bb79e869b37a6ddf8ef1/raw/10c057b39a4dccbe39d3151be78c686dcd1101aa/guestlist.xml')
    .then(res => {
      const xml = XMLMapping.load(res.data);
      var guests  = XMLMapping.tojson(xml);
      this.setState({guests: guests});
    });
  }
```

The results of the json in console:

```
Object{
  dataset{
   record{
    0{
      company{
        $t: "Skippad"
      }
      first_name{
        $t: "Keith"
      }
      last_name{
        $t: "Cook"
      }
    }
    1{
      company{
        $t: "Skippad"
      }
      first_name{
        $t: "Keith"
      }
      last_name{
        $t: "Cook"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I'm using this function to map the object and then using a map() within it:

```
function mapObject(object, callback) {
  return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
    return callback(key, object[key]);
  });
}
```

This is what the final mapping of the data looks like:

```
{mapObject(this.state.guests, (key, value) => {
  return <div key={key}>
    {value.record
    .filter(
      (item,index) => {
        return (
          item.first_name.$t.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
          //item.last_name.$t.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
          //item.company.$t.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
        )
      }
    )
    .map((item,index) => {
      return <div className="columns is-mobile" key={index}>
        <div className="column" key={index}>{item.first_name.$t} {item.last_name.$t} <span class="is-hidden-tablet"><br />{item.company.$t}</span></div> 
        <div className="column is-hidden-mobile" >{item.company.$t}</div>
        <div className="column is-hidden-mobile">
          <EmailFormdisplay guestid={index} />
        </div>
        <div className="column is-hidden-mobile">
          <PhoneFormdisplay guestid={index} />
          </div>
          <div className="column is-hidden-tablet is-one-third-mobile">
          <Dropdown>
            <DropdownTrigger></DropdownTrigger>
              <DropdownContent>
                <div className="columns">
                  <div className="column">
                    <EmailFormdisplay guestid={index} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="column">
                    <PhoneFormdisplay guestid={index} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </DropdownContent>
          </Dropdown>
          </div>
      </div>;
    })}
    </div>
  })}
```

Is there a better way of doing this without using mapObject() and a map() within it?

Any kind of feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this code works you should probably ask this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherMoore didn't know there was a code review stackexchange.

Comment: I can't seem to close it and put it on codereview.

Comment: If anyone is looking for the answer or feedback or advice on this, it can be found here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177608/react-better-way-of-mapping-this-data/177618?noredirect=1#comment336859_177618